# How to autoplay image sliding using appIntro

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using [AppIntro](https://github.com/apl-devs/AppIntro) to view splash screen as viewpager.

I read the doc of this API and I am looking do how to autoplay it once it is launched.

Can someone help me please.

Regards

Comment: Please look into timers/handlers and use the pager object to set the appropriate slide: `pager.setCurrentItem(SLIDE);`

Comment: Well you can use Handler() to keep the pages displayed for specific time and then execute the nextSlide() method in the after your specific time interval

Comment: @AkhileshPatil thank you, please i already encouter this solution but i don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Use Timer Class for the auto increment of viewPager current selection

```
    final int seconds =2;
    final int delayTime =0;

    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int selection=viewPager.getCurrentItem();
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(selection++);
        }
    }, delayTime, seconds * 1000);
        }
    });
```